# C++ Strings in Read Function from fcntl.h

Tags: c++, unix, fcntl, unistd.h

In my basic Linux Programming course at college, we use fcntl.h and unistd.h
Using C++ strings, I get the following:

```
statusOfFunction = write(fileDescriptor, input.c_str(), input.length());
```

This line works. I get a file created, with the contents of input string. But, why doesn't any of these lines work:

```
statusOfFunction = read(fileDescriptor, reading.c_str(), 10);
Error: No matching function call to "read"

statusOfFunction = read(fileDescriptor, reading, 10);
Error: No matching function call to "read"

statusOfFunction = read(fileDescriptor, &reading, 10);
No error throws up, but does not get executed

statusOfFunction = read(fileDescriptor, &reading.c_str(), 10);
Error: No matching function call to "read"
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnw208uo3xurqxf/Basic%20Unix%20Operations%20on%20Text%20Files.cpp?dl=0

Here is the program, for your reference.
Thank you! :)

Comment: What's `reading`? You need to match the prototype to `read`, which according to `man 2 read` is `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` so you need reading to be a void pointer to a buffer large enough to hold 10 bytes (or whatever your `count` is).

Comment: In your basic Linux Programming course, have they not-yet-covered what `const` means?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first

```
statusOfFunction = read(fileDescriptor, reading.c_str(), 10);
```

is that `c_str` is declared to return a *`const`* pointer. Otherwise this is the closes to the correct method.

First of all you need to create a string that contains at least 10 characters:

```
std::string temp_string(10, ' ');  // Creates a string contains 10 spaces
```

Then you need to pass a non-constant pointer, which you can get by using the address-of operator `&` and the strings array-indexing operator `[]`:

```
statusOfFunction = read(fileDescriptor, &temp_string[0], temp_string.length());
```

And finally you assign it to the actual string:

```
reading = std::string(temp_string, 0, statusOfFunction);
```

Of course, you should check `statusOfFunction` so it's not an error (when it `-1`) or end of file (when its `0`).

---

All the other methods you tried for reading are just very wrong.

Comment: It still does not work :(
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnw208uo3xurqxf/Basic%20Unix%20Operations%20on%20Text%20Files.cpp?dl=0
Please check the code. Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: @NadeemAhmedNajeeb For starters, you miss the bit where I tell you to create the string with memory allocated for it. What you do in the linked code is read into an empty string, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: I did try, but I get an error then too:
    std:: string sample(10);
    No matching constructor for initialisation
Also, I tried using sample[10], thinking [] might be overloaded. Turns out I am wrong there too

Comment: @NadeemAhmedNajeeb Sorry, I forgot that the constructor needs extra arguments, updated answer. The major problem here is that you are using `std::string` for something it's not really designed for. And `operator[]` *is* overloaded in the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class, please read the linked reference.

Comment: Joachim, thanks a ton! :)
The two things I missed out of my code, both you rectified:
1 Missed out: lseek(fileDescriptor, 0, SEEK_SET);
2 The missing argument in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

read expects a buffer to fill the data read.

What you're doing is dangerous.

You should allocate a char buffer and make sure you add the NULL char after the string length as `read` will not do it for you.
the c_str function exposes the internal buffer used by the string class. It is read only.

Overwriting the string object itself will cause a crash for sure when later used.

```
char buff[11];
size_t bytes_read = read(fd, buff, 10);
buff[bytes_read] = 0; // terminate string
string myString(buff);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
So, using C++ strings is not preferable in the Unix library by large?

Comment: the way you used them is not recommended. there are C++ classes for I/O. mixing low level C functions with the string class is dangerous. in any case `c_str()` returns a const array - so you should never modify it.

Comment: Can C++ I/O be used for Unix as well?

Comment: C++ IO classes work perfectly well on Linux and Unix.

Comment: Wow. Here in India, as far as Unix programming goes, the only answer is C. Guess being adventurous helps Thank you! ☺️

Comment: C is the way to go with Kernel-mode Unix programming. For user mode stuff C++ is a better option.